# No response from server when submitting form data from front end

Tags: post, httpresponse, formik, yup, nodejs-express-server

While building a MERN project from EdRoh on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K8YELRmUb5o), i got this problem where on the register page when i submit the form data it should redirect to login page and the data should get stored on mongodb database.
When i checked it with Postman it is working fine i am able to post the data to database.
But when i try to register through front end on register page, my page is not redirecting and my server is also not responding with any error or success message. I have installed morgan which logs the http status code with the CRUD method. But it is not logging anything.I have also installed cors.
I am using multer to store the data and JWT for token verification on backend and using formik for forms and yup to send the data to my server through the api i built.

I am linking the screenshot and the code which i think might be useful for anyone to helpme.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tr3Wt.jpg)

This is form.jsx file which has two forms component which are rendered conditionally.

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import {
  Box,
  Button,
  TextField,
  useMediaQuery,
  Typography,
  useTheme,
} from '@mui/material';
import EditOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/EditOutlined';
import { Formik } from 'formik';
import * as yup from 'yup';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { setLogin } from 'state';
import Dropzone from 'react-dropzone';
import FlexBetween from 'components/FlexBetween';

const registerSchema = yup.object().shape({
  firstName: yup.string().required('required'),
  lastName: yup.string().required('required'),
  email: yup.string().email('invalid email').required('required'),
  password: yup.string().required('required'),
  location: yup.string().required('required'),
  occupation: yup.string().required('required'),
  picture: yup.string().required('required'),
});

const loginSchema = yup.object().shape({
  email: yup.string().email('invalid email').required('required'),
  password: yup.string().required('required'),
});

const initialValuesRegister = {
  firstName: '',
  lastName: '',
  email: '',
  password: '',
  location: '',
  occupation: '',
  picture: '',
};

const initialValuesLogin = {
  email: '',
  password: '',
};

const Form = () => {
  const [pageType, setPageType] = useState('login');
  const { palette } = useTheme();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const isNonMobile = useMediaQuery('(min-width:600px)');
  const isLogin = pageType === 'login';
  const isRegister = pageType === 'register';

  const register = async (values, onSubmitProps) => {
    // this allows us to send form info with image
    const formData = new FormData();
    for (let value in values) {
      formData.append(value, values[value]);
    }
    formData.append('picturePath', values.picture.name);

    const savedUserResponse = await fetch(
      'http://localhost:3001/auth/register',
      {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData,
      }
    );
    const savedUser = await savedUserResponse.json();
    onSubmitProps.resetForm();

    if (savedUser) {
      setPageType('login');
    }
  };

  const login = async (values, onSubmitProps) => {
    const loggedInResponse = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/auth/login', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify(values),
    });
    const loggedIn = await loggedInResponse.json();
    onSubmitProps.resetForm();
    if (loggedIn) {
      dispatch(
        setLogin({
          user: loggedIn.user,
          token: loggedIn.token,
        })
      );
      navigate('/home');
    }
  };

  const handleFormSubmit = async (values, onSubmitProps) => {
    if (isLogin) await login(values, onSubmitProps);
    if (isRegister) await register(values, onSubmitProps);
  };

  return (
    <Formik
      onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}
      initialValues={isLogin ? initialValuesLogin : initialValuesRegister}
      validationSchema={isLogin ? loginSchema : registerSchema}
    >
      {({
        values,
        errors,
        touched,
        handleBlur,
        handleChange,
        handleSubmit,
        setFieldValue,
        resetForm,
      }) => (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <Box
            display='grid'
            gap='30px'
            gridTemplateColumns='repeat(4, minmax(0, 1fr))'
            sx={{
              '& > div': { gridColumn: isNonMobile ? undefined : 'span 4' },
            }}
          >
            {isRegister && (
              <>
                <TextField
                  label='First Name'
                  onBlur={handleBlur}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  value={values.firstName}
                  name='firstName'
                  error={
                    Boolean(touched.firstName) && Boolean(errors.firstName)
                  }
                  helperText={touched.firstName && errors.firstName}
                  sx={{ gridColumn: 'span 2' }}
                />
                <TextField
                  label='Last Name'
                  onBlur={handleBlur}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  value={values.lastName}
                  name='lastName'
                  error={Boolean(touched.lastName) && Boolean(errors.lastName)}
                  helperText={touched.lastName && errors.lastName}
                  sx={{ gridColumn: 'span 2' }}
                />
                <TextField
                  label='Location'
                  onBlur={handleBlur}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  value={values.location}
                  name='location'
                  error={Boolean(touched.location) && Boolean(errors.location)}
                  helperText={touched.location && errors.location}
                  sx={{ gridColumn: 'span 4' }}
                />
                <TextField
                  label='Occupation'
                  onBlur={handleBlur}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  value={values.occupation}
                  name='occupation'
                  error={
                    Boolean(touched.occupation) && Boolean(errors.occupation)
                  }
                  helperText={touched.occupation && errors.occupation}
                  sx={{ gridColumn: 'span 4' }}
                />
                <Box
                  gridColumn='span 4'
                  border={`1px solid ${palette.neutral.medium}`}
                  borderRadius='5px'
                  p='1rem'
                >
                  <Dropzone
                    acceptedFiles='.jpg,.jpeg,.png'
                    multiple={false}
                    onDrop={(acceptedFiles) =>
                      setFieldValue('picture', acceptedFiles[0])
                    }
                  >
                    {({ getRootProps, getInputProps }) => (
                      <Box
                        {...getRootProps()}
                        border={`2px dashed ${palette.primary.main}`}
                        p='1rem'
                        sx={{ '&:hover': { cursor: 'pointer' } }}
                      >
                        <input {...getInputProps()} />
                        {!values.picture ? (
                          <p>Add Picture Here</p>
                        ) : (
                          <FlexBetween>
                            <Typography>{values.picture.name}</Typography>
                            <EditOutlinedIcon />
                          </FlexBetween>
                        )}
                      </Box>
                    )}
                  </Dropzone>
                </Box>
              </>
            )}

            <TextField
              label='Email'
              onBlur={handleBlur}
              onChange={handleChange}
              value={values.email}
              name='email'
              error={Boolean(touched.email) && Boolean(errors.email)}
              helperText={touched.email && errors.email}
              sx={{ gridColumn: 'span 4' }}
            />
            <TextField
              label='Password'
              type='password'
              onBlur={handleBlur}
              onChange={handleChange}
              value={values.password}
              name='password'
              error={Boolean(touched.password) && Boolean(errors.password)}
              helperText={touched.password && errors.password}
              sx={{ gridColumn: 'span 4' }}
            />
          </Box>

          {/* BUTTONS */}
          <Box>
            <Button
              fullWidth
              type='submit'
              sx={{
                m: '2rem 0',
                p: '1rem',
                backgroundColor: palette.primary.main,
                color: palette.background.alt,
                '&:hover': { color: palette.primary.main },
              }}
            >
              {isLogin ? 'LOGIN' : 'REGISTER'}
            </Button>
            <Typography
              onClick={() => {
                setPageType(isLogin ? 'register' : 'login');
                resetForm();
              }}
              sx={{
                textDecoration: 'underline',
                color: palette.primary.main,
                '&:hover': {
                  cursor: 'pointer',
                  color: palette.primary.light,
                },
              }}
            >
              {isLogin
                ? "Don't have an account? Sign Up here."
                : 'Already have an account? Login here.'}
            </Typography>
          </Box>
        </form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
};

export default Form;
```

this is app.js file

```
import { BrowserRouter, Navigate, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Homepage from 'scenes/homePage';
import LoginPage from 'scenes/loginPage';
import ProfilePage from 'scenes/profilePage';
import { useMemo } from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { CssBaseline, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material';
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { themeSettings } from './theme';

function App() {
  const mode = useSelector((state) => state.mode);
  const theme = useMemo(() => createTheme(themeSettings(mode)), [mode]);
  const isAuth = Boolean(useSelector((state) => state.token));
  return (
    <div className='app'>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <CssBaseline />
          <Routes>
            <Route
              path='/'
              element={<LoginPage />}
            />
            <Route
              path='/home'
              element={isAuth ? <Homepage /> : <Navigate to='/' />}
            />
            <Route
              path='/profile/:userId'
              element={isAuth ? <ProfilePage /> : <Navigate to='/' />}
            />
          </Routes>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

this is the auth controller logic for backend.

```
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import User from '../models/User.js';

/* REGISTER USER */
export const register = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const {
      firstName,
      lastName,
      email,
      password,
      picturePath,
      friends,
      location,
      occupation,
    } = req.body;

    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt();
    const passwordHash = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);

    const newUser = new User({
      firstName,
      lastName,
      email,
      password: passwordHash,
      picturePath,
      friends,
      location,
      occupation,
      viewedProfile: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000),
      impressions: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000),
    });
    const savedUser = await newUser.save();
    res.status(201).json(savedUser);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
  }
};

/* LOGGING IN */
export const login = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    const user = await User.findOne({ email: email });
    if (!user) return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'User does not exist. ' });

    const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
    if (!isMatch) return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'Invalid credentials. ' });

    const token = jwt.sign({ id: user._id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
    delete user.password;
    res.status(200).json({ token, user });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
  }
};
```

this is index.js file from backend

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import cors from 'cors';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import multer from 'multer';
import helmet from 'helmet';
import morgan from 'morgan';
import path from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import authRoutes from './routes/auth.js';
import userRoutes from './routes/users.js';
import postRoutes from './routes/posts.js';
import { register } from './controllers/auth.js';
import { createPost } from './controllers/posts.js';
import { verifyToken } from './middleware/auth.js';
import User from './models/User.js';
import Post from './models/Post.js';
import { users, posts } from './data/index.js';

/* CONFIGURATIONS */
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);
dotenv.config();
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(helmet());
app.use(helmet.crossOriginResourcePolicy({ policy: 'cross-origin' }));
app.use(morgan('common'));
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '30mb', extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '30mb', extended: true }));
app.use(cors());
app.use('/assets', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/assets')));

/* FILE STORAGE */
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'public/assets');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname);
  },
});
const upload = multer({ storage });

/* ROUTES WITH FILES */
app.post('/auth/register', upload.single('picture'), register);
app.post('/posts', verifyToken, upload.single('picture'), createPost);

/* ROUTES */
app.use('/auth', authRoutes);
app.use('/users', userRoutes);
app.use('/posts', postRoutes);

/* MONGOOSE SETUP */
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 6001;
mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => {
    app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server Port: ${PORT}`));

    /* ADD DATA ONE TIME */
    // User.insertMany(users);
    // Post.insertMany(posts);
  })
  .catch((error) => console.log(`${error} did not connect`));
```

I tried to send data to my server using frontend and the server should have responsed with 201 status code and my data should have been inserted in my database.

I was expecting that when my user register then they will be redirected to login page and after logging in they should see the homepage.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for posting your question. I have compared your code with the original code from the tutorial, and everything appears to be the same. I have also completed this great tutorial and tested the registration behavior in my own project.

Here's what I noticed: It seems impossible to register without a profile picture. In your screenshot, I can clearly see that no picture is provided. However, in your `registerSchema`, the `picture` field is marked as required.

```
const registerSchema = yup.object().shape({
  firstName: yup.string().required('required'),
  lastName: yup.string().required('required'),
  email: yup.string().email('invalid email').required('required'),
  password: yup.string().required('required'),
  location: yup.string().required('required'),
  occupation: yup.string().required('required'),
  picture: yup.string().required('required'),   <<<< !HERE!
});
```

To resolve this issue, try selecting an image when you register on the frontend.

I hope this helps